# The relation between two different definitions of Affine sets

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization

I am following a presentation, which says that for an affine set $L \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ it is: $$L=\left\{x|Ax=b \right\}$$

for some $A,b$.

The first definition of $L$ as an affine set is given as; given two points $x$ and $y$ with $x,y \in L$, it is is always $\alpha x + \beta y \in L$ where $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\alpha + \beta = 1$. This is very clear and straightforward. But I did not get its relation with $L=\left\{x|Ax=b \right\}$. As far as I remember from my linear algebra classes which I took years ago, $Ax=b$ is a non-homogeneous system of linear equations. But I cannot see how it is connected with the definition of an affine set. I need some insight here.

Comment: $A(\alpha x+\beta y)=\alpha Ax+\beta Ay=\alpha b+\beta b=b$.

Comment: you usually built such sets for example affine or convex whatever based on a distance or simply an equation. Whenever this equation is met they are elements of your set. The definition of an affine set is made as ..... and you immediately see that those ones who are elements of this set arise from the affine equation .... similarly to convex sets.

Comment: Some questions: 1) Are there some constraints on $A$ here? As far as I know, we can't just pick two arbitrary $A$ and $b$, since there can be no $x$ which provides the equation $Ax=b$. For example, should $A$ be $nxn$ sized when $x$ are $n$ dimensional vectors? 2) Assuming that $Ax=b$ and $Ay=b$ ,it is shown that $A(\alpha x + \beta y) = b$, but this is only a side of the equivalence. How can it be shown that $L=\left\{ x|Ax=b\right\}$ holds when the first definition of affine set for $L$ holds? (The one which says $x,y \in L$, $\alpha + \beta = 1$ implies $\alpha x + \beta y \in L$)

Answer (score 1):

You have two definitions of affine, one that is given via generators:
 $L$ is affine if there are $A,c$ with ${x:Ax=c}$ (the set of all affine sets is generated by all $A,c$).

One that is given via constraints:
 $L$ is affine if for every $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ with $a+b=1$ and $x,y\in L$ there is also $ax+by\in L$ (this is a constraint on a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$).

You need to show that every set satisfying one definition also satisfies the other. The easier direction is showing that something generated via $A,c$ has the latter property. The harder direction is finding generators $A,c$ for a set $L$ satisfying the constraint. By the way, I personally favor another definition:
 $L$ is affine if there is a linear subset $K$ and a vector $c$ such that $L=\{x+c|x\in K\}$. You should look up your linear algebra results for describing a linear set $K$ via either its generators or constraints, and for converting between the two descriptions. Can you show that for any $c\in L$ the set $K=\{x-c|x\in L\}$ is linear for either definition of affine linear?

Specifically, in terms of your question, a set $K=\{x|Ax=0\}$ and a set $K'$ such that for all $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ and all $x,y\in K'$ the sum $ax+by$ is again in $K'$ are both linear.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sorry, I am heavily confused at that stage, so let me sum up what I am currently having in my mind: An affine set is actually a line, according to the definition with constraints $\alpha + \beta = 1$, $x,y \in L$ and $\alpha x + \beta y \in L$. If I understood correctly, if this is true for $L$, then we can always find a $A$ and $b$ such that for all $x\in L$ it is $Ax=b$ is that right?So,how can we directly show from the constraint definition that we always have a $A,b$; how should one construct a proof here? Sorry,I could not follow your alternative definition with $K$

Comment: Ok, I see where you are confused. An affine linear set is not a line, it is not necessarily one-dimensional. An affine line is a set $L_{xy}= \{ax+by|a+b=1\}$ for some $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$. An affine set is a set $L$ that contains the affine line $L_{xy}$ for all points $x,y\in L$. Does that help?

Comment: You are right that one can directly show from the  constraint definition that there are $A,b$. I would proceed as follows: Show that the set $K=\{x-y|x,y\in L\}$ is linear. Using that show that there is an $A$ such that $K=\{Ax=0\}$. Then fix any $y\in L$ and define $b'=Ay$. Show $L=\{x+y|x\in K\}=\{x|Ax=b'\}$. Please note that you used $b$ with two different meanings in your question, be careful with that.

Comment: Ok, let's try to follow you. We build the set $K$ by using the differences of each $x,y$ pair belonging to affine $L$. By using the affine set constraints, we show that $K$ is linear. Because of that, we can find a $A$, such that $K$ is actually the solution set of the equation $Ax=0$. Now, I approach like that: for each $x'$, $Ax'=0$, it is $\exists x,y \in L$ such that $x'=x-y$. We know that for each $x\in L$ it is $Ax=b'$. So this leads to: $$ \forall x', Ax'=0 \implies \exists x \in L, Ax=b'$$. But I cannot reach to $L=\left\{x|Ax=b'\right\}$ here. What am I missing?

Comment: Ok, if you agree that for all $x\in L$ we have $Ax=b'$ then we need to show that for all $x$ with $Ax=b'$ we have $x\in L$. We know there is $y\in L$ with $Ay=b'$ (by choice of $b'$). Thus $A(x-y)=0$, which means $x-y\in K$. $K$ is made up of differences of elements of $L$, so there are $x',y'\in L$ with $x'-y'=x-y$. Thus $x=1x'-1y'+1y$, a linear combination of elements $L$ whose coefficients sum to one, by this property of $L$ we have $x\in L$.

Comment: You only have that the linear combination of two elements with coefficients that sum to one is again in $L$ by this definition of affine, but from that you can prove it for three elements, or any finite number.